# Rabbit MQ Web UI Queue Error

Tags: rabbitmq

When I click Queues in the Rabbit MQ Web UI, instead of going to the Queues page I get a error on the bottom of the page I'm on.  This is a new install on a Windows 2012 VM.  I have another Windows 2012 (non-VM) that works just fine. This happend right after the first install.  I un-installed (and deleted the directory in my profile), then re-installed and I have the same problem.  I can still create and use queue's within code, the only problem I have is viewing the Queues page in the Web UI.  How can I troubleshoot the error?  JSON for error follows:

`Got response code 500 with body {"error":"JSON encode error: {bad_term,#{error_logger => true,kill => true,size => 0}}","reason":"While encoding: \n[{total_count,4},\n {item_count,4},\n {filtered_count,4},\n {page,1},\n {page_size,100},\n {page_count,1},\n {items,\n [[{memory,105168},\n {message_stats,\n [{deliver,0},\n {deliver_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {deliver_no_ack,1038},\n {deliver_no_ack_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {get,0},\n {get_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {get_no_ack,0},\n {get_no_ack_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {publish,1038},\n {publish_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {publish_in,0},\n {publish_in_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {publish_out,0},\n {publish_out_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {ack,0},\n {ack_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {deliver_get,1038},\n {deliver_get_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {confirm,0},\n {confirm_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {return_unroutable,0},\n {return_unroutable_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {redeliver,0},\n {redeliver_details,[{rate,0.0}]}]},\n {reductions,3116188},\n {reductions_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {messages,0},\n {messages_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {messages_ready,0},\n {messages_ready_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {messages_unacknowledged,0},\n {messages_unacknowledged_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {idle_since,<<\"2016-07-28 15:08:23\">>},\n {consumer_utilisation,''},\n {policy,''},\n {exclusive_consumer_tag,''},\n {consumers,1},\n {recoverable_slaves,''},\n {state,running},\n {reductions,3116188},\n {garbage_collection,\n [{max_heap_size,#{error_logger => true,kill => true,size => 0}},\n {min_bin_vheap_size,46422},\n {min_heap_size,233},\n {fullsweep_after,65535},\n {minor_gcs,2}]},\n {messages_ram,0},\n {messages_ready_ram,0},\n {messages_unacknowledged_ram,0},\n {messages_persistent,0},\n {message_bytes,0},\n {message_bytes_ready,0},\n {message_bytes_unacknowledged,0},\n {message_bytes_ram,0},\n {message_bytes_persistent,0},\n {head_message_timestamp,''},\n {disk_reads,0},\n {disk_writes,0},\n {backing_queue_status,\n {struct,\n [{mode,default},\n {q1,0},\n {q2,0},\n {delta,[delta,undefined,0,undefined]},\n {q3,0},\n {q4,0},\n {len,0},\n {target_ram_count,infinity},\n {next_seq_id,11},\n {avg_ingress_rate,0.0},\n {avg_egress_rate,0.0},\n {avg_ack_ingress_rate,0.0},\n {avg_ack_egress_rate,0.0}]}},\n {node,rabbit@PACKDEV},\n {arguments,{struct,[]}},\n {exclusive,false},\n {auto_delete,false},\n {durable,true},\n {vhost,<<\"/\">>},\n {name,<<\"Monnit\">>}],\n [{memory,105048},\n {message_stats,\n [{deliver,0},\n {deliver_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {deliver_no_ack,895},\n {deliver_no_ack_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {get,0},\n {get_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {get_no_ack,0},\n {get_no_ack_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {publish,895},\n {publish_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {publish_in,0},\n {publish_in_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {publish_out,0},\n {publish_out_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {ack,0},\n {ack_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {deliver_get,895},\n {deliver_get_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {confirm,0},\n {confirm_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {return_unroutable,0},\n {return_unroutable_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {redeliver,0},\n {redeliver_details,[{rate,0.0}]}]},\n {reductions,4619870},\n {reductions_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {messages,0},\n {messages_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {messages_ready,0},\n {messages_ready_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {messages_unacknowledged,0},\n {messages_unacknowledged_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {idle_since,<<\"2016-07-28 15:08:22\">>},\n {consumer_utilisation,''},\n {policy,''},\n {exclusive_consumer_tag,''},\n {consumers,1},\n {recoverable_slaves,''},\n {state,running},\n {reductions,4619870},\n {garbage_collection,\n [{max_heap_size,#{error_logger => true,kill => true,size => 0}},\n {min_bin_vheap_size,46422},\n {min_heap_size,233},\n {fullsweep_after,65535},\n {minor_gcs,2}]},\n {messages_ram,0},\n {messages_ready_ram,0},\n {messages_unacknowledged_ram,0},\n {messages_persistent,0},\n {message_bytes,0},\n {message_bytes_ready,0},\n {message_bytes_unacknowledged,0},\n {message_bytes_ram,0},\n {message_bytes_persistent,0},\n {head_message_timestamp,''},\n {disk_reads,0},\n {disk_writes,0},\n {backing_queue_status,\n {struct,\n [{mode,default},\n {q1,0},\n {q2,0},\n {delta,[delta,undefined,0,undefined]},\n {q3,0},\n {q4,0},\n {len,0},\n {target_ram_count,infinity},\n {next_seq_id,564},\n {avg_ingress_rate,0.0},\n {avg_egress_rate,0.0},\n {avg_ack_ingress_rate,0.0},\n {avg_ack_egress_rate,0.0}]}},\n {node,rabbit@PACKDEV},\n {arguments,{struct,[]}},\n {exclusive,false},\n {auto_delete,false},\n {durable,true},\n {vhost,<<\"/\">>},\n {name,<<\"Persist\">>}],\n [{memory,24048},\n {message_stats,\n [{deliver,0},\n {deliver_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {deliver_no_ack,190},\n {deliver_no_ack_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {get,0},\n {get_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {get_no_ack,0},\n {get_no_ack_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {publish,190},\n {publish_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {publish_in,0},\n {publish_in_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {publish_out,0},\n {publish_out_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {ack,0},\n {ack_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {deliver_get,190},\n {deliver_get_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {confirm,0},\n {confirm_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {return_unroutable,0},\n {return_unroutable_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {redeliver,0},\n {redeliver_details,[{rate,0.0}]}]},\n {reductions,773120},\n {reductions_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {messages,0},\n {messages_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {messages_ready,0},\n {messages_ready_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {messages_unacknowledged,0},\n {messages_unacknowledged_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {idle_since,<<\"2016-07-28 11:53:36\">>},\n {consumer_utilisation,''},\n {policy,''},\n {exclusive_consumer_tag,''},\n {consumers,1},\n {recoverable_slaves,''},\n {state,running},\n {reductions,773120},\n {garbage_collection,\n [{max_heap_size,#{error_logger => true,kill => true,size => 0}},\n {min_bin_vheap_size,46422},\n {min_heap_size,233},\n {fullsweep_after,65535},\n {minor_gcs,1}]},\n {messages_ram,0},\n {messages_ready_ram,0},\n {messages_unacknowledged_ram,0},\n {messages_persistent,0},\n {message_bytes,0},\n {message_bytes_ready,0},\n {message_bytes_unacknowledged,0},\n {message_bytes_ram,0},\n {message_bytes_persistent,0},\n {head_message_timestamp,''},\n {disk_reads,0},\n {disk_writes,0},\n {backing_queue_status,\n {struct,\n [{mode,default},\n {q1,0},\n {q2,0},\n {delta,[delta,undefined,0,undefined]},\n {q3,0},\n {q4,0},\n {len,0},\n {target_ram_count,infinity},\n {next_seq_id,2},\n {avg_ingress_rate,0.0},\n {avg_egress_rate,0.0},\n {avg_ack_ingress_rate,0.0},\n {avg_ack_egress_rate,0.0}]}},\n {node,rabbit@PACKDEV},\n {arguments,{struct,[]}},\n {exclusive,false},\n {auto_delete,false},\n {durable,true},\n {vhost,<<\"/\">>},\n {name,<<\"PresidentAlert\">>}],\n [{memory,21864},\n {message_stats,\n [{deliver,0},\n {deliver_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {deliver_no_ack,2},\n {deliver_no_ack_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {get,0},\n {get_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {get_no_ack,0},\n {get_no_ack_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {publish,2},\n {publish_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {publish_in,0},\n {publish_in_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {publish_out,0},\n {publish_out_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {ack,0},\n {ack_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {deliver_get,2},\n {deliver_get_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {confirm,0},\n {confirm_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {return_unroutable,0},\n {return_unroutable_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {redeliver,0},\n {redeliver_details,[{rate,0.0}]}]},\n {reductions,10640},\n {reductions_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {messages,0},\n {messages_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {messages_ready,0},\n {messages_ready_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {messages_unacknowledged,0},\n {messages_unacknowledged_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {idle_since,<<\"2016-07-26 14:02:08\">>},\n {consumer_utilisation,''},\n {policy,''},\n {exclusive_consumer_tag,''},\n {consumers,0},\n {recoverable_slaves,''},\n {state,running},\n {reductions,10640},\n {garbage_collection,\n [{max_heap_size,#{error_logger => true,kill => true,size => 0}},\n {min_bin_vheap_size,46422},\n {min_heap_size,233},\n {fullsweep_after,65535},\n {minor_gcs,0}]},\n {messages_ram,0},\n {messages_ready_ram,0},\n {messages_unacknowledged_ram,0},\n {messages_persistent,0},\n {message_bytes,0},\n {message_bytes_ready,0},\n {message_bytes_unacknowledged,0},\n {message_bytes_ram,0},\n {message_bytes_persistent,0},\n {head_message_timestamp,''},\n {disk_reads,0},\n {disk_writes,0},\n {backing_queue_status,\n {struct,\n [{mode,default},\n {q1,0},\n {q2,0},\n {delta,[delta,undefined,0,undefined]},\n {q3,0},\n {q4,0},\n {len,0},\n {target_ram_count,infinity},\n {next_seq_id,3},\n {avg_ingress_rate,0.007746137582597711},\n {avg_egress_rate,0.22867095182081107},\n {avg_ack_ingress_rate,0.0},\n {avg_ack_egress_rate,0.0}]}},\n {node,rabbit@PACKDEV},\n {arguments,{struct,[]}},\n {exclusive,false},\n {auto_delete,false},\n {durable,true},\n {vhost,<<\"/\">>},\n {name,<<\"myqueue\">>}]]}]"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue when you use erlang 19.

https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/876

The version `3.6.4` will support erlang 19.

Meanwhile you can use an older erlang version

Comment: Works great, thanks!  If anyone else runs into this, I tried uninstalling Erlang then installing the previous version but then the RabbitMQ service wouldn't start.  I reinstalled RabbitMQ and everything worked great.